# How get screen type in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

i used this above and run it different emulator like large,medium,small. but i get toast normal screen..how to solve it

```
    if ((this.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & 
                    Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 
                        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Large screen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(((this.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & 
                    Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 
                        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL)) {
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Normal screen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else if(((this.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & 
                    Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 
                        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL)) {
                  Toast.makeText(this, "small screen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Xlarge screen",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Comment: Hi you can get the Screen density 

      DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

You can get info on the display from the **[DisplayMetrics][1]** struct:


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

Comment: Check this code it may useful `DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
switch(metrics.densityDpi){
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                break;
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                 break;
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                 break;
}`

Comment: Thank u androidgeek..it's work fine for me...J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

read below code :- 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

now put if condition.